# NameError: global name 'linked' is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following code on the leetcode problem "add two numbers". However, I get the error "NameError: global name 'linked' is not defined". What am I doing wrong?

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
        """
        :type l1: ListNode
        :type l2: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        number_list_one = l1.val + (l1.next).val*10 + ((l1.next).next).val * 100
        number_list_two = l2.val + (l2.next).val*10 + ((l2.next).next).val * 100
        result = number_list_one + number_list_two
        linked.val = result - (l1.next).val*10 - ((l1.next).next).val * 100 - (l2.next).val*10 - ((l2.next).next).val * 100
        linked.next.val = result - l1.val - ((l1.next).next).val * 100 - l2.val - ((l2.next).next).val * 100
        linked.next.val = result - l1.val - (l1.next).val*10 - l2.val - (l2.next).val*10
        return linked
```

I expected the linked.val to create a new ListNode

Comment: create a class variable named `linked=None` in class `Solution`

Comment: you haven't instance `linked`, so you cannot access `linked.val`. You should do `linked=ListNode()` which means `linked` is a `ListNode` object that can access `linked.val` or `linked.next`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `linked` as an instance of `ListNode`.  See the code below.

```
class Solution(object):

    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
        """
        :type l1: ListNode
        :type l2: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        linked = ListNode() # add this line to create a new ListNode
        number_list_one = l1.val + (l1.next).val * 10 + ((l1.next).next).val * 100
        number_list_two = l2.val + (l2.next).val * 10 + ((l2.next).next).val * 100
        result = number_list_one + number_list_two
        linked.val = result - (l1.next).val * 10 - ((l1.next).next).val * 100 - (l2.next).val * 10 - (
            (l2.next).next).val * 100
        linked.next.val = result - l1.val - ((l1.next).next).val * 100 - l2.val - ((l2.next).next).val * 100
        linked.next.val = result - l1.val - (l1.next).val * 10 - l2.val - (l2.next).val * 10
        return linked
```